Problem with compactitem environment in CV
I found a CV template on the overleaf Website. When I tried to compile it, the section with the compactitem didn't appear on the rendered PDF file and I haven't got a clue what the problem is here. Can anybody help please. Thanks in advance. Here is the latex code:
\input{Preamble_CV.tex}

%%% Begin Document
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-0.5cm}
    \hfill\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image}
    \vspace{-5cm}
\end{wrapfigure}

\MyName{Jane Doe}

\sepspace

%%% Personal details
%\NewPart{Personal details}

\SimpleEntry{01.01.1990, born in Sample, Sampleland}
\SimpleEntry{Samplestreet 1}
\SimpleEntry{1000 Samplecity}
\SimpleEntry{012 345 67 89}
\SimpleEntry{sample@sample.com}

%%% Education
\NewPart{Education}
\TimeEntryFocus{2.2018 - dato}
{Master of Sample Science}
{at Sample Uni}
{Focus on sample topics\\
%Average to date: 5\\
Expected graduation in March of 2020}
{Master Thesis: Sample Title\\
Further Projects:
\begin{compactitem}[-]
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
\end{compactitem}
}

\sepspace

\TimeEntry{9.2013 - 9.2017}
{Bachelor of Sample Science}{at Sample Uni}
%{Average: 5}
{Bachelor Thesis: Sample Title\\
Further Projects:
\begin{compactitem}[-]
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
\end{compactitem}
}

\sepspace

\TimeEntry{8.2009 - 6.2013}
{Matura with focus on Sample}
{at Sample School}
%{Average: 5.}
{\begin{compactitem}[-]
    \item Sample Title
\end{compactitem}
}

%%% Work experience
\NewPart{Work experience}
\TimeEntry{9.2017 - 2.2018}{Sample Internship}{at Sample AG}{
\begin{compactitem}[-]
    \item Sample task
    \item Sample task
    \item Sample task
\end{compactitem}
}

%%% Skills and Qualifications
\NewPart{Skills and Qualifications}
\NewSubPart{Programming Languages}
\TitleEntry{Advanced skills}{Samples}
\TitleEntry{Basic skills}{Samples}

\NewSubPart{Languages}
\TitleEntry{Native tongue}{Sample language}
\TitleEntry{Basics}{Sample language}

%%% Interests
\NewPart{Interests}
\SimpleEntry{Sample Interests}

\end{document}

And this is the code from the referenced file Preamble_CV:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=24mm,right=24mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                % For textit, textbf, etc
\usepackage{graphicx}                               % For includegraphics
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                % For wrapfig environment
\usepackage{paralist}                               % For compactitem 

\pagestyle{empty}                                   % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{%                                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}%                       
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-10pt}{1pt}
}
\subsectionfont{%                                   % Change font of \subsection command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}%                       
    %\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-10pt}{1pt}
}

%%% Macros
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}               % Vertical space macro
\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NewSubPart}[1]{\subsection*{#1}}

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{
    \noindent
    \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n} #1 \hfill        % Name
    \par \normalsize \normalfont
}

\newcommand{\SimpleEntry}[1]{
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0          % Indentation
    #1 \par                                         % Entry 
}

\newcommand{\TimeEntry}[4]{
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0          % Indentation
    \parbox{3cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}                                 % Time
    }
    \textbf{#2}                                     % What
    \text{#3}                                       % Work
    \normalsize \par
}

\newcommand{\TimeEntryFocus}[5]{
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0          % Indentation
    \parbox{3cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}                                 % Time
    }
    \textbf{#2}                                     % What
    \text{#3} \par                                  % School
    \noindent\hangindent=3.7cm\hangafter=0
    \textit{#4}                                     % Average, Focus, etc
    \normalsize \par
}

\newcommand{\TimeEntryDesc}[4]{
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0          % Indentation
    \parbox{3cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}                                 % Time
    }
    \textbf{#2}                                     % What
    \text{#3} \par                                  % Work
    \noindent\hangindent=4cm\hangafter=0 \parbox{11cm}{\vspace{0.2em}\small #4}  % Description
    \normalsize \par
}

\newcommand{\TimeEntryFocusDesc}[5]{
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0          % Indentation
    \parbox{3cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}                                 % Time
    }
    \textbf{#2}                                     % What
    \text{#3} \par                                  % School
    \noindent\hangindent=3.7cm\hangafter=0
    \textit{#4} \par                                  % Average, Focus, etc
    \noindent\hangindent=4cm\hangafter=0 \parbox{12cm}{\vspace{0.2em}\small #5}  % Description
    \normalsize \par
}

\newcommand{\TitleEntry}[2]{                     
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0            % Indentation
    \parbox{3cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}
    }                                               % Title
    #2 \par                                         % Entry 
}

\newcommand{\TitleEntryLong}[2]{                     
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0            % Indentation
    \parbox{14cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}
    }                                               % Title
    #2 \par                                         % Entry 
}


Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you get any errors or warnings when you compile the code?

No, I don't get any errors. It's just that this section doesn't appear on the PDF document after compilation.

It only says that command \underline and \underbar have changed

The preamble file defines \newcommand{\TimeEntry}[4] and \newcommand{\TimeEntryFocus}[5] that are take 4 or 5 arguments respectively, however in the body of those two commands the 4th argument (for \TimeEntry) and the 5th (for \TimeEntryFocus) argument is not actually used anywhere, i.e., there is no #4 or #5 in the body of the commands. The argument is therefore consumed by the command but then disappears (without warnings or errors) because it is not used.
However, there are two similar commands that take 4 or 5 arguments and actually use them, which are \TimeEntryDesc and \TimeEntryFocusDesc. You can use those commands instead.
Example snippet using the alternative commands:
%%% Education
\NewPart{Education}
\TimeEntryFocusDesc{2.2018 - dato}
{Master of Sample Science}
{at Sample Uni}
{Focus on sample topics\\
%Average to date: 5\\
Expected graduation in March of 2020}
{Master Thesis: Sample Title\\
Further Projects:
\begin{compactitem}[-]
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
\end{compactitem}
}

\sepspace

\TimeEntryDesc{9.2013 - 9.2017}
{Bachelor of Sample Science}{at Sample Uni}
%{Average: 5}
{Bachelor Thesis: Sample Title\\
Further Projects:
\begin{compactitem}[-]
    \item Sample project
    \item Sample project
\end{compactitem}
}

Result:

Note that most likely the original two commands were intended to be used in case there was no further description, and the parameter for the number of arguments is a mistake in the code. If you want to use this functionality then it would make sense to modify the preamble file to lower the number of arguments:
\newcommand{\TimeEntry}[3]{
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0          % Indentation
    \parbox{3cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}                                 % Time
    }
    \textbf{#2}                                     % What
    \text{#3}                                       % Work
    \normalsize \par
}

\newcommand{\TimeEntryFocus}[4]{
    \noindent\hangindent=0.5cm\hangafter=0          % Indentation
    \parbox{3cm}{                                   % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}                                 % Time
    }
    \textbf{#2}                                     % What
    \text{#3} \par                                  % School
    \noindent\hangindent=3.7cm\hangafter=0
    \textit{#4}                                     % Average, Focus, etc
    \normalsize \par
}

